# How to check upload progress using http package?

Tags: flutter, dart, http, dio

Basically how to implement `onSendProgress` of `Dio` using the `http` package?

Most solutions online are about reading a file upload progress.

Answer (score -1):

You can see progress on console. Also you can implement progress bar using the info.

```
try {
          await Dio().download(
              url,
              savePath, //where to save
              onReceiveProgress: (received, total) {

                if (total != -1) {
                  setState(() {
                    progress = (received / total * 100).toStringAsFixed(0) + "%";
                  });
                  print((received / total * 100).toStringAsFixed(0) + "%");
                  //you can build progressbar feature too
                }
              });
         
        } on DioError catch (e) {
          print(e.message);
        }
```